# Add export default to DatagridBody

Tags: react-admin

When trying the example at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#body-element
We are this error message : 
Attempted import error: 'DatagridBody' is not exported from 'react-admin'

Comment: What version of React Admin are you using? It seems to work with the version 2.5.3 (ex. https://codesandbox.io/s/74q1nlo3ox )

Comment: In my packages.json it was the version 2.4.4 and i checked my node_modules it was the same version.

Comment: it's ok with version 2.6